# Is it safe to swap uninitialized members in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a hash table, and I've got a bucket type that holds my key values, so I can hold them in unions and leave them uninitialized to avoid requiring DefaultConstructible for them:

```
template <class K, class V>
struct bucket {
     bucket() : hash(SENTINEL) {}
     bucket(uint64_t hash, K&& k, V&& v) 
       : hash(hash), key(std::forward(k)), val(std::forward(v)) {}

     <copy constructors>

    ~bucket() { 
         if (hash != SENTINEL) {
             key.~K();
             val.~V();
         }
      }

     uint64_t hash;
     union { K key; }
     union { V key; }
};
```

My question, then, is something like the = operator, which I would usually write with the copy-and-swap idiom:

```
bucket& operator =(bucket other) {
     using std::swap;
     swap(hash, other,hash);
     swap(key,  other.key);
     swap(val,  other.val);
}
```

Is this still safe, even with unitialized key and val?

Comment: That's not how you avoid requirements like default constructible. Check out placement new.

Comment: I'm aware of placement new, I'm doing this because I'm also going to specialize bucket for the case where there's no value (for a set).  I'm really just curious if this is safe or not.

Comment: You also cannot read a `union` member other than the one last assigned to, so that breaks your design, too.

Comment: It's not.  Swapping something means reading from it before writing from it in all cases. Reading from uninitialized is UB.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that reading an uninitialized variable is Undefined Behaviour (except if is is `unsigned char`) - and swap counts as reading.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Can you elaborate on  why unsigned char  is  an exception?

Comment: @Nir Friedman not off the top of my head, no. But I seem to have this memory that the standard has an exception for that case. I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: @JesperJuhl AFAIK, that exception was introduced in C++14.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister There's no reason why you can't use placement new and still be able to specialize for a set.

Comment: @NirFriedman The standard guarantees that every bit pattern for an `unsigned char` represents a number. You may thus read an uninitialized `unsigned char` and are guaranteed to get some number. That's not particularly useful usually, but it *is* technically legal.

Comment: @molbdnilo right you are - paragraph 11.6 point 12.

Comment: And why you would not use STL containers? I don't see what is the "requiring DefaultConstructible" problem.

Answer (score 5):

This fails even earlier: It is UB to read a `union` member other than the one last assigned to.

If you have not assigned a value to any member, you also can't read any member, regardless of the type or any "reading uninitalized variables" rules.

---

As I mentioned in the comments, the correct way to avoid the default constructible requirement would be using placement new.

Comment: OK, that's what I was looking for, I did put them in separate unions to prevent that read/write issue, but the reading from uninitialized being undefined is a deal breaker.

Comment: Are you certain? A cursory glance at the standard (§12.3.5) suggests that in this case the lifetime of `key` and `value` would be implicitly started when `operator=` is invoked on those union members? But perhaps I have misunderstood?

Comment: I could use placement new with this, but it's unececesary in this case because I can just construct them directly, I'll probably still use this notion, but not swap out the members, they'll just get destroyed and reconstructed.

Comment: @ThomasRussell The assignment in the swap would make the members of the union active, but evaluating the function arguments reads the inactive members, and that's UB already.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused - re-reading it appears that if we have `union u { A a; }; U u; u.a;` is enough to _implicitly_ activate `u.a`? In this particular example, things will be undefined anyway (reading from uninitialised variables). But I'm not sure the union accesses are UB? I could of course (and probably am) be completely wrong! :)

Comment: @ThomasRussell I'm not 100% sure on that one tbh. I guess that's fine? Might be worth asking that in a new question, tag [language-lawyer].

Comment: Re-reading (yet again); it seems that implicit activation only occurs when the left operand of an assignment operator contains some sub-expression that would otherwise be undefined behaviour. Thus the function argument evaluation would be UB after all!

Comment: @ThomasRussell On that I was pretty certain, the `u.a;` is the part I would not put money on.

Comment: The `u.a` is not part of the left operand of an assignment expression, thus should not result in implicit activation I believe.

Comment: @ThomasRussell There may be some context specific rules applying here, but again, I'm not sure on that one, I cannot give you a definite answer. That's probably better suited for people like Barry or Yakk.